# Customize devise flash messages based on model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, devise

I am using Devise for authentication in my rails app. There are two devise models in the app, `admin` and `customer`.

Customer model uses `mobile_number` for authentication instead of the usual email_id field. However, the admin field uses `email_id` for authentication.

Now, the issue I am facing is related to the default flash messages shown by devise.

Consider, when a user enters invalid login credentials, the message is

```
'Invalid email or password'
```

I want to customize this message based on models. So, if admin enters incorrect credentials, message is:

```
'Invalid email or password'
```

If customer enters the same, it is:

```
'Invalid mobile number or password'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Devise gem supports different kinds of locale files like for English, Arabic, Chinese etc for showing all flash messages related to Devise authentication in different languages.

Refer this [link](http://www.localeapp.com/projects/377). Choose the English version. In that you could see when you need to show `invalid email or password` flash message. So the solution is,

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      customer:
        invalid: 'Welcome user, you are signed in.'
        not_found_in_database: 'Welcome user, you are signed in.'
      admin:
        invalid: 'Invalid mobile number or password'
        not_found_in_database: 'Invalid mobile number or password'
```

Hope this helps :)